# Visual fatigue in Ubuntu

Tags: xorg, monitor, samsung, xrandr, framerate

Hello I have a problem with ubuntu.
Visual fatigue is the problem. After using my pc, my eyes feel really tired. The problem? I have an LED monitor so it's not the technology that's the problem, ubuntu is the problem. Xorg to be more specific.
This actually only happens in linux.
In windows 7 I don't have any problem with this.
It is very strange and I don't know what to do.
Please help I want to use ubuntu again... without my eyes burning D:
The only thing that I know is this:
https://veuwer.com/i/3kgn
But this seems specialized. Is a 59 framerate normal?
Is my monitor incompatible?
Thanks for your help.
My monitor is a samsung s19d300

Comment: Try software called `redshift` helps ease eyestrain

Comment: Biggest differences between the look of windows & other OS's are usually the fonts & colours. Maybe try **Anti-aliasing** or ** Font smoothing**? Are there any different (manufacturer's) drivers available for your video hardware? Tried a different monitor?

Answer (score 7):

59.79 is really 60. Sometimes refresh rates are off of 60 by a tiny bit, but it shouldn't matter. Any visual fatigue you're experiencing could be fixed by using a different desktop environment, such as GNOME, MATE, KDE, or LXDE. You could also try using a background with slightly dimmer colors.

However, I feel that eye fatigue is somewhat subjective. If you experience it while using your computer, I recommend maybe seeing an eye doctor or taking a break from the screen for a while. There really isn't a catchall fix (and I've honestly never heard of anyone complain of this before), but here are some more things you can try:

[F.lux](http://justgetflux.com) -- Puts a yellow tint over whatever the computer is displaying - good at night.

Lower your screen brightness -- Ubuntu might actually make your screen brighter than Windows or something weird like that.

**Suggestion from [hbdgaf](https://askubuntu.com/users/5768/hbdgaf)**: If you have a webcam, you can try [this program](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/06/yawls-let-your-webcam-adjust-your.html), which adjusts your screen brightness automatically based on the amount of light your webcam sees. For people that have a problem focusing on two different lighting conditions, this problem would happen mostly at night/in dark surroundings.  Darker colors do the same thing.  Dull the differential between your screen and the background.

I said it before, but a different desktop environment really might help. GNOME and MATE both use darker colors than Unity.

Increase your font size. Maybe your computer's font is too small. Refer [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-font-size.html) for more info.

Hopefully one of those helps. Since it's really a problem with your eyes or configuration, we can't provide a definitive answer.

Comment: I tried every  desktop environment, every distro, and i don't now why happen, like i said only happens in linux, in windows i can stay all the day without problems.Its weird.

Comment: It might be the font then, but I'd still talk to an eye doctor.

Comment: Yeah i have to, i have headaches when i read :P,but i still seeing this weird,why not windows?why are refresh rate in 60 in some resolutions but in the native 59*+?I'm confused.

Comment: Each desktop *should* have a (sometimes easy, sometimes not) way to change the colours and fonts, can mimic a different desktop's theme without actually installing a different desktop.